# Calling other page through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay let's say I have a page that inserts data into database

page1.php

```
//INSERT CODE 
//HTML FORM
```

Whenever I access page1.php, url at the top seems like this

```
www.abc.com/page1.php
```

if I am at the home page of website and url seems to be

```
www.abc.com/home
```

At the same page I can call other page's div through jquery ajax call but the url seems not to change. Even if i call any other page url won't change at all...

What I am looking for is that a solution that when I call the page1.php to the same page that is home.php url changes like this

```
www.abc.com/home?view=page1
```

or

```
www.abc.com/home/page1
```

and also do I have to write page1.php functionality of DATABASE INSERT in home.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your URL by

```
var myNewUrl = 'www.abc.com/home?view=page1';
window.history.replaceState('', '', myNewUrl);
```

Comment: Would it not redirect to other page?

Comment: it will just change the URL

Comment: And I have to write INSERT functionality in home.php page? right?

Comment: its depends on where are you sending ajax request

Comment: and yes on home.php if you are sending ajax request to home.php

Comment: I doesn't just change the url but also redirects!

Answer (score 1):

So you can't change the URL without redirecting. What you can do though is to change the hash. This will not redirect, but it will show the value in URL.

```
// AJAX CALL
// GET NAME OF PAGE YOU CALLED
// SET IT TO "var toHash"

// Whenever AJAX call finishes make a callback function with this code.

document.location.hash = toHash;

// or you can something like this for each time it changes at all.

window.onhashchange = function(){
    var doThis = document.location.hash;    
    if (doThis=="#thisLink")
        doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual implementation on two pages?! I am stuck in creating hash!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not required. window.location.replace() will simulate an HTTP redirect.

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

Comment: I do not want to redirect!

Comment: do you want to inject one page in another?